# How to overlay image with transparent background properly?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a mini game with images overlayed on camera views. From this image it should be clear what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I just want the gun to be there without the background rectangle remainder (which I deleted in paint).

Here's the relevant code:

```
<body>

    <!-- Camera -->
    <main id="camera">

        <!-- Camera sensor -->
        <canvas id="camera--sensor"></canvas>
        
        <!-- Camera view -->
        <video id="camera--view" autoplay playsinline></video>
        
        <!-- Camera output -->
        <img src="//:0" alt="" id="camera--output">

        
        <!-- Crosshair -->
        <img src="crosshair.png" class="crosshair" />
        
        <!-- Gun Model -->
        <img src="gun_model_1.png" class="gunmodel" />
        
        
        
        <!-- Camera trigger -->
        <button id="camera--trigger">SHOOT</button>

    </main>

    <!-- Reference to your JavaScript file -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>

    <!-- Reference to adapter.js -->
    <script src="adapter-min.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.gunmodel {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 60%;
  display: inline;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0%) translateX(0%);
}
```

Clearly my CSS isn't doing what I want.

Comment: Does `.gunmodel { background: transparent; }` do anything?

Comment: CSS has nothing to do here, if the image is transparent it will be transparent, if not then not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming since the issue is related to the nature of the image used which is out of the scope of HTML/CSS

Answer (score 1):

Paint can't save transparent images. It looks like the image that you put there isn't actually transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your "PNG" is actually a PNG.

Comment: Damn... this was the case. I got fooled when I saved the image because it had that similar "transparent" background from paint. I fixed the image and it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to verify that your image is transparent is to open the image in the browser (I tried it in opera and chrome) and if the image in its background is black, it is because it is transparent, if the image comes out with the squares, then it is not transparent

Example of image that was transparent but is not 
[enter link description here](https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/85-856434_imagenes-sin-fondo-renders-png-cartoon-transparent-png.png)

here the other case
[enter link description here](https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/80-809178_imagenes-sin-fondo-formato-clipart.png)

Comment: enter link description here